# How can I upload information from a php form on a different site?

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a form that needs to upload the information retrieved to an entirely separate site.

My form's "action" is to send the information to itself in order to validate information as well as see, if the required fields are input. If no errors are found, an email is sent with a message that includes the information from the form.

My code for the index page generally looks like this:

```
<?php include('action_page.php'); include('config.php')?>

<form method="POST" name="email_form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-25">
      <label for="subject"><span class="error">* <?php echo $titleErr;?></span> Subject <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-75">
      <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Please input a subject for the email" style="height:46px"><?php echo $title;?></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="emails"><span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?> 
      </span> Email <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
  <p style="color:#0071c5">Please choose which group(s) to send this to: 
  </p>
    <?php foreach($emails as $value): ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="email[]" value='<?php echo $value ?>'<?php if (isset($_POST['email']) && in_array($value, $_POST['email'])) echo 'checked="checked"';?> ><?php echo $value ?>&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

My action page then sends an email using the php mail() function.

What I want to do is upload the body of the email on a separate website, which runs similarly to how Wikipedia is run - anyone can edit a page even if you're not the owner of the page.

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how to even start. I'm able to use a header on my action page that can link my form to a different page, but this doesn't autofill like I want it to.

For example:

```
if(mail($mail_to, $title, $msg, implode("\r\n", $headers))){
    header('Location: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Japanese_aircraft_carrier_Ry%C5%ABj%C5%8D&action=edit'); 
}
```

sends the user to the appropriate Wikipedia page, but I'm not able to see any of my variables, that my form stored.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing more of your code, but you will likely need API access to perform a POST request. [Here is documentation from Wikipedia](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API_talk:Upload#Real_world_example_with_PHP) about working with their API in PHP.